SwiftData Different behaviour between iOS 17 and iOS 18
I'm brand new in SwiftUI development. I created an app, I was almost at the end with fine tuning when I got weird behaviours with the iOS 18 version when using Swift Data.
I think I'm part of the problem but I can not figure out how to solve it.
I've searched, spent so many hours and feel a bit disappointed not succeeding.
Here is my first problem :
I've two models :
@Model
class Song: Codable {
    var uuid: UUID = UUID()
    var text: String = ""
    var creationDate: Date = Date.now
    var updatingDate: Date  = Date.now
    var status: Int = 0
    var nbRead: Int = 0
    var speed: Float = 0.5
    var language: String = ""

    enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case uuid, text, creationDate, updatingDate, status, nbRead, speed, language
    }

    @Relationship(inverse: \Genre.songs)
    var genres: [Genre]?

    init(uuid: UUID, text: String, creationDate: Date,   updatingDate: Date, status: Int, nbRead: Int, speed: Float, language: String) {
        self.uuid = uuid
        self.text = text
        self.creationDate = creationDate
        self.updatingDate = updatingDate
        self.status = status
        self.nbRead = nbRead
        self.speed = speed
        self.language = language
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        try container.encode(uuid, forKey: .uuid)
        try container.encode(text, forKey: .text)
        try container.encode(creationDate, forKey: .creationDate)
        try container.encode(updatingDate, forKey: .updatingDate)
        try container.encode(status, forKey: .status)
        try container.encode(nbRead, forKey: .nbRead)
        try container.encode(speed, forKey: .speed)
        try container.encode(language, forKey: .language)
    }

    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        uuid = try container.decode(UUID.self, forKey: .uuid)
        text = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .text)
        creationDate = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .creationDate)
        updatingDate = try container.decode(Date.self, forKey: .updatingDate)
        status = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .status)
        nbRead = try container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .nbRead)
        speed = try container.decode(Float.self, forKey: .speed)
        language = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .language)
    }
}

and
enter code here
@Model
class Genre {
    var name: String = ""
    var color: String = "Red"
    var songs: [Song]?

    init( name: String, color: String) {
        self.name = name
        self.color = color
    }
}

I want to list all songs organised by sections :
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

struct SongsListView: View {
private var searchingText: String

@Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
@Query(sort: \Genre.name) private var genres: [Genre]    
@Query var songs : [Song]

    init(searchText: String)
    {
        if !searchText.isEmpty {
            let predicate = #Predicate<Song> { song in
                song.text.localizedStandardContains(searchText)
            }
            _songs =  Query(filter: predicate)

        }
        searchingText = searchText
    }

var body: some View {
    HStack{
        List{
            if !songs.isEmpty {
                ForEach(genres, id: \.name){ genre in
                    Section(header: Text(genre.name)){
                        ForEach (songs){song in
                            if let songGenres = song.genres {
                                if songGenres.contains(genre){
                                    NavigationLink {
                                        SongView(song: song)
                                    } label: {
                                        Text(song.text)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onDelete { indexSet in
                    indexSet.forEach { index in
                        let song = songs[index]
                        modelContext.delete(song)
                    }
                }
                Section(header: Text("Without Genre")) {
                    ForEach (songs){song in
                        if let songGenres = song.genres {
                            if songGenres.isEmpty{
                                NavigationLink {
                                    SongView(song: song)
                                } label: {
                                    Text(song.text)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .onDelete { indexSet in
                        indexSet.forEach { index in
                            let song = songs[index]
                            modelContext.delete(song)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            
        }
        .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
       }
    }
}

Here is the MainView:
import SwiftData
import SwiftUI

struct MainView: View {

enum AddOrEdit {
    case add, edit
}

@State private var searchText = ""

@Environment(\.modelContext) private var modelContext
@Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss

var option: AddOrEdit

var body: some View {
    VStack{
        ZStack{
            
            HStack{
                Text("Songs").bold()
                    .padding(.leading)
                Spacer()
            }
            
            HStack{
                Spacer()
                Button(action: {
                    dismiss()
                }, label: {
                    Image(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill")
                        .padding(.trailing)
                })
            }
            
        }
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack{
                SongsListView(searchText: searchText)
                    .searchable(text: $searchText, prompt:"Search for a song...")
            }
            Button {
                modelContext.insert(Song(uuid: UUID(), text: "New song", creationDate: Date(), updatingDate: Date(), status: 0, nbRead: 0, speed: Float(1.0), language: "fr-FR"))
            }label: {
                Image(systemName: "plus.circle.fill")
                //.imageScale(.large)
                    .font(.title)
                }
            }
            .offset(y: -10)
            .scrollContentBackground(.hidden)
        }
    
    }
}

On iOS 17, creating a new song adds it directly to the list in the Without Genre section.
On iOS 18, it takes around 30 seconds to be added.
I tried to decompose the issue into steps to identify the problem. I think I use the wrong way and could try to go with Core Data. However, I need to learn and to understand how to get the same results without waiting 30 seconds to complete.
I did a video, and I have a demo project to illustrate if necessary.
Here you can download code and see video

You didn't include SongView, is it irrelevant to the question? And you didn't include any code for adding a new song even though you say that is what the issue is about.

Hi Joakim, SongView is not relevant. However, the main view where songs are added can be. So I edited the question to add it.

If you feel that ios 18 has altered behavior for the worse, please file a bug report with Apple.

U're right, and in the same time, I need to understand what was wrong. Because, I don't feel  100% confident about what I did. So I'm looking for advices before.

SongView is not included in the code, so at this time your code is not reproducible. Also, please take a moment to edit your post, there are brackets outside the code section which make it difficult to copy. Also, the initializer is missing from the Song class.

I edited the post because of the bracket outside. I also added several hours before a link with the code and the video. Hope that helps.

That link doesn't work

I uploaded a new one available for 7 days. I don't know why the previous was deleted.

Note, you cannot just add Codable to a class, such as @Model class Song: Codable {..} and expect it to work. You need to provide the
appropriate init(from decoder: Decoder) and func encode(to encoder: Encoder).
In any case, it is best to have separate structs for Codable. Note also, you want to make sure that in your ForEach(genres, id: \.name) the elements are unique, no genres elements with the same name.

I edited the code above to add the two functions (there were existing as required but I dit not add them in the code block. For the ForEach, you're right, I changed to use .id but it does not change. There are still around 30 seconds for element to come.

Finally, I found where the issue was :
Section(header: Text("Without Genre")) {
    ForEach (songs){song in
        if let songGenres = song.genres { // <-- PB is here !
            if songGenres.isEmpty{
                NavigationLink {
                    SongView(song: song)
                } label: {
                    Text(song.text)
                }
             }
        }
    }
    .onDelete { indexSet in
        indexSet.forEach { index in
             let song = songs[index]
             modelContext.delete(song)
         }
     }
 }

Then I decided to bypass by calling a function to get the song's genre.
 Section(header: Text("Without Genre")) {
    ForEach (songs){song in
        let songGenres = getGenres(song) { // Change has been made
            if songGenres.isEmpty{
                NavigationLink {
                    SongView(song: song)
                } label: {
                    Text(song.text)
                }
             }
        }
    }
    .onDelete { indexSet in
        indexSet.forEach { index in
             let song = songs[index]
             modelContext.delete(song)
         }
     }
 }

And the func :
func getGenres(song: Song) -> [Genre] {
    if let genres = song.genres {
        return genres
    } else {
        return []
    }
}

